# Reduce Truth table with Karnaugh Map

Tags: computer-science, discrete-mathematics, karnaugh-map

I am trying to reduce a boolean expression with a K-map. But when I make the map I end up with three true values which is not possible to make a map with.

Is there a way to simplify this map?

The original expression was:

```
Y1 = A1 B1 A2' B2' + A1 B1 A2 B2' + A1 B1 A2' B2
```

Thanks a lot for the help. The picture shows the truth tables and the k-map

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplifying the map does not make much sense, I suppose you mean simplify the expression, in which case yes, you can. You would have to make two groups of two ones (trues), getting Y1 = A1B1A2' + A1B1B2'.

Comment: Thanks  a lot that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the response for Nevado above I was able to come up with a solution by grouping two adjacent values in two groups.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using it in a logical circuit it might be sometimes a surprisingly better approach to use the CNF(POS) instead of DNF(SOP).

If you take the simplified DNF: `y1 = a1·b1·¬a2 + a1·b1·¬b2` as is (without any optimization using NANDs or NORs), you'll end up needing **two 3-input ANDs**, **one 2-input OR** and **two invertors**.

It might be better to use the CNF: `y1 = a1·b1·(¬a2 + ¬b2)`, where **only one of each logical function** is used along with the **two invertors**.

Circling the larger bunches of `0` results in that:

[image: Minimal CNF]